# How do I pass an object location into a vertex shader?

Tags: shaders, python, vertex, blender-game-engine

I am using *Blender Game Engine*. I want to create a large flat plane, and deform it locally near a moving object.

So far (despite being a beginner at shaders) I've written a vertex shader for the plane which moves the vertices to their correct positions (constant positions, for now).

I cannot find a way to swap that constant location with an object's location updated every frame, while the shader is running. I am not even sure if it's possible. I only want to access a specific object's center from the shader.

Comment: I don't know Blender, but what you want to do is create a uniform variable in the vertex shader, and set the uniform to the object's location every frame.  Maybe with a bit of searching you can find how to handle uniforms in Blender.

Comment: @Nathan Reed thats exactly what i did. I defined a uniform3f value in the shader, and i am just setting its new values on every frame. Now i need to find out if its possible to pass a list of locations for every object on the scene. But anyway my initial problem is solved :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable in your shader that holds this object location. In GLSL, you'd create a [uniform variable](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29); this is a variable which has the same value throughout the invocation of the shader (thus, "uniform;" you may see developers more familiar with D3D refer to these kind of variable as a "shader constant" variable as well).

Every time you want to render something with this shader, you'd [set the uniform variable](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform) to the value you want.

---

That said, however, it looks like you are just using this uniform to displace some object in the world. The more common approach to this is to use a [world transformation matrix](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) for the object which is applied in the shader. This is implemented (in modern OpenGL) as a matrix uniform variable, much like your simple vector uniform, but also allows for rotation and scaling and is the more common approach. It will also scale equally well to an [instancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_instancing) scenario where you have several objects sharing the same geometry but in different world positions (as it sounds like, from your comments, you are wanting to have eventually).